# Getting No response when click on Jmeter Executable file

Tags: jmeter

When I am trying to launch jmeter by clicking on the executable jar file, I am not getting any response.

```
2023-07-17 18:35:34,147 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting LAF to: com.github.weisj.darklaf.DarkLaf:com.github.weisj.darklaf.theme.DarculaTheme
2023-07-17 18:35:34,406 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loaded icon properties from org/apache/jmeter/images/icon.properties
2023-07-17 18:35:34,433 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[#29,AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.label.DarkLabelUI (in unnamed module @0x214b199c) cannot access class sun.swing.SwingUtilities2 (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.swing to unnamed module @0x214b199c
at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.label.DarkLabelUI.paint(DarkLabelUI.java:95) ~[darklaf-core-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:852) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1128) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:961) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1137) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:961) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1137) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:961) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5325) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBufferedFPScales(RepaintManager.java:1720) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1629) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1569) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1336) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1114) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39) ~[?:?]
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:75) ~[?:?]
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:112) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:2005) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3959) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:889) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:861) ~[?:?]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400) ~[?:?]
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:861) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:834) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:784) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1897) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714) ~[?:?]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400) ~[?:?]
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) [?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) [?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) [?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) [?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) [?:?]
2023-07-17 18:35:34,490 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: An error occurred:
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.text.DarkTextUI (in unnamed module @0x214b199c) cannot access class sun.swing.DefaultLookup (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.swing to unnamed module @0x214b199c
at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.text.DarkTextUI.getInputMap(DarkTextUI.java:341) ~[darklaf-core-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.text.DarkTextUI.installKeyboardActions(DarkTextUI.java:303) ~[darklaf-core-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.installUI(BasicTextUI.java:836) ~[?:?]
at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.text.DarkTextUI.installUI(DarkTextUI.java:322) ~[darklaf-core-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:740) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setUI(JTextComponent.java:338) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.updateUI(JTextComponent.java:348) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.<init>(JTextComponent.java:322) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.JTextArea.<init>(JTextArea.java:213) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.JTextArea.<init>(JTextArea.java:149) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.AbstractJMeterGuiComponent.<init>(AbstractJMeterGuiComponent.java:84) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui.<init>(TestPlanGui.java:69) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
```

I believe its not able to access some of the UI themes (dark mode). Is it some compatibility issue?
Can anyone please suggest why we get this error and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.laf=CrossPlatform
```

and at least this error will go away.

More information:

- [Look and Feel configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#laf_config)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

However you might start facing other issues because you're using Java 9+ which needs to be properly configured so you

- either need to pass the [following parameters](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/bin/jmeter.bat#L112) somehow:

  ```
   --add-opens java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED
  ```
- or downgrade to [Java 8](https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk8/)
- or just use `jmeter.bat` file for starting JMeter (you can double-click it as well if your computer doesn't have a keyboard)

Also be informed that it's [recommended to use the latest version of JMeter when possible](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.6.2](https://lists.apache.org/thread/49dnwvyozy535ogwqvdvbkwkgk0xkrrl) (or whatever is the latest version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)